# Using PowerShell Core 7 in SSMS

Tags: powershell, ssms, powershell-core

How can I configure SSMS to use PowerShell Core 7+ instead of Windows PowerShell?

I have searched several times and found nothing.

Comment: Powershell is run from the Windows\System32 folder.  To have more than one version of Powershell see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_editions?view=powershell-7.3.  Cmdlets are run in the order of the PSModulePath.

Comment: @jdweng, thank you for your reply. I already have both Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell Core 7.3 on my system. The question is about how to get the context-sensitive `Start PowerShell` menuitem to run pwsh.exe and not powershell.exe. Is that possible?

Comment: You can put pwsh.exe in to a script (ps1) and then call the script from SSMS.  See following for other options : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver16